# Googledrive API Upload file via PHP return Error

Tags: google-drive-api

Have Problem with Upload any file to Google Drive Cloud via PHP, 
Another Process Listing files, Children Listen, File details fork fine.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("File Upload Testing");
$client->setClientId('myID');
$client->setClientSecret('mySecret');
$client->setScopes(
    array(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly",
    ));

    $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId("0B1OLO5r_T5znT3dRTUdNNGVxdms");

    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $file->setParents(array($parent));
    $file->setTitle("File.png");
    $file->setDescription("File pnd desc");
    $file->setMimeType("image/png");

    $content = file_get_contents('images/resim.jpg');

    try{
       $file = $service->files->insert($file, array(
           'data' => $content,
           'mimeType' => 'image/png',
           'uploadType' => 'multipart',
           'fields' => 'id'));
        printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
    } catch( Execution $e){
       echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

image in correct path!, wenn i remove data from array file than, upload process successfully but empty not content, with data param, return always 404 not Found!,
have couldn't found this problem, have any idea?